# lxml unicode output issue

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests

New to python and lxml so please bear with me. Now stuck with what appears to be unicode issue. I tried .encode, beautiful soup's unicodedammit with no luck. Had searched the forum and web, but my lack of python skill failed to apply suggested solution to my particular code. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

sourceUrl = "http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty.htm"

sourceHtml = requests.get(sourceUrl)

htmlTree = lxml.html.fromstring(sourceHtml.text)

for stockCodes in htmlTree.xpath('''/html/body/printfriendly/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/table/tr/td'''):
    string = stockCodes.text
    print string
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? Or add a line `print type(string)` before `print string` to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code like this `python lx.py`, I don't get the error. But when I send the result to sdtout `python lx.py > output.txt`, it occurs. So try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import lxml.html
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

This allows you to switch from the default ASCII to UTF-8, which the Python runtime will use whenever it has to decode a string buffer to unicode.

Comment: Thanks. You don't see error when you redirect output to screen? May I ask your Python version? I'm running 2.7.3

Comment: I'm using 2.6. Which OS do you use， Linux or Windows？

Answer (score 0):

The text attribute always returns pure bytes but the content attribute should try to encode it for you. You could also try: `sourceHTML.text.encode('utf-8')` or `sourceHTML.text.encode('ascii')` but I'm fairly certain the latter will cause that same exception.